# Google Map React Throwing "refused to apply inline styles error"

Tags: reactjs, content-security-policy, inline-styles, google-map-react

CSP Issue:

[image]

Our project have strict content security issue i.e. we are using `style-src *` and cannot add `unsafe-inline` option here.
I am getting "refused to apply inline styles error" and CSS is not applied for google Map due above strict content security policy.

**Steps to reproduce**

1)Clone create react app

2)Install `google-map-react` v2.1.9

3)Add content security policy header inside your inside your `public/index.html` file

```
 <script> 
    var cspScriptPolicy = "default-src 'none'; connect-src * 'self'; font-src *;img-src * data:; script-src * 'self' maps.googleapis.com; style-src *; manifest-src 'self';"; 
        // Inject a tag to disable inline scripts 
        var cspMetaTag = document.createElement('meta'); 
        cspMetaTag.setAttribute('http-equiv', 'Content-Security-Policy'); cspMetaTag.setAttribute('content', cspScriptPolicy); 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cspMetaTag); </script>
```

4. Use inline Styles prop from google map react library
5. Create build and serve it on localhost .

**Expected behavior ::**
google map should not throw inline style errors and style should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps itself uses inline `<style>` therefore it requires `'unsafe-inline'` in the 'style-src' directive.

Officially GMAP does not supports nonces, however the problem of inline styles can be solved by [using 'nonce-value'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65441914/not-able-to-implement-strict-content-security-policy-with-google-maps-apis/67417230#67417230), but StreetView will not works.